# MPPlayableContentManagerContext error in Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I was working with a iOS project and Xcode 6.3.2 and the project was compiling and running perfect, but Today I have updated to Xcode 6.4 and now I can't compily the project because "MPPlayableContentManagerContext" from MediaPlayer framework are failing. I have many errors in this framework class.

Someone know the reason?

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you,

Kind regards.

Comment: Same happening to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of the use of NBUAvailability.h https://gist.github.com/rivera-ernesto/7228433

You have to add the version 8_4 to the list:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_SOFT_MAX_REQUIRED < __IPHONE_8_4
#undef __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_8_4
#define __AVAILABILITY_INTERNAL__IPHONE_8_4 __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("8.4")
#define __NBU_APICHECK_8_4(_ios)            __NBU_AVAILABILITY_STARTING("8.4")
#else
#define __NBU_APICHECK_8_4(_ios)            CF_AVAILABLE_IOS(_ios)
#endif
```