# MPMoviePlayerViewController crashing immediatly XCODE 6.4 and IOS 8.4

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

```
var player:MPMoviePlayerViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController()
player.moviePlayer.stop()
player.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.Streaming
player.moviePlayer.contentURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "http://srv6.zoeweb.tv:1935/z330-live/stream/playlist.m3u8")
self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(player)
```

The moment I call this code that application crashes with below error:

> 2015-07-12 20:08:35.108 VoicelotsMobile[7283:208796] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of
>   AVPlayer'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f8cc65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000109d39bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45  2   AVFoundation
>
>   0x000000010c2094ef -[AVPlayerItem _attachToFigPlayer] + 0     3
>
>   AVFoundation                        0x000000010c1fc732 -[AVPlayer
>   _attachItem:andPerformOperation:withObject:] + 298    4   AVFoundation                        0x000000010c21c698 -[AVQueuePlayer insertItem:afterItem:] + 142     5
>
>   MediaPlayer                         0x0000000107765d98 -[MPQueuePlayer
>   insertItem:afterItem:] + 58   6   MediaPlayer
>
>   0x00000001076d6220 -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncPlayerItems] + 1651    7 
>   MediaPlayer                         0x00000001076d5b62
>   -[MPAVQueueCoordinator _syncItems] + 1597     8   MediaPlayer                         0x00000001076d496e -[MPAVQueueCoordinator
>   reloadItemsKeepingCurrentItem:] + 871     9   MediaPlayer
>
>   0x00000001077335fc -[MPAVPlaylistManager connectPlayer] + 421     10 
>   MediaPlayer                         0x0000000107658256
>   -[MPAVController _connectAVPlayer] + 218  11  MediaPlayer                         0x0000000107627ac8 -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew setMovieSourceType:] +
>   122   12  MediaPlayer                         0x000000010762a0d3
>   -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _movieSourceTypeAvailableNotification:] + 251    13  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107f5c54c
>   __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12   14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107e5aa04
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 2484   15  Foundation                          0x00000001085ad968 -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66   16  MediaPlayer
>   0x00000001076f31c4 **30-[MPMovie _determineMediaType]_block_invoke +
>   261   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cda9186
>   _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12     18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010cdc8614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8     19  libdispatch.dylib
>   0x000000010cdb0a1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1664   20 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107ef41f9
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE** + 9    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107eb5dcb __CFRunLoopRun
>   + 2043    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107eb5366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470   23  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010a917a3e GSEventRunModal + 161  24  UIKit
>   0x0000000108a6d8c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282   25  VoicelotsMobile
>   0x000000010736a397 main + 135     26  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010cdfc145 start + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Please help. I tried lots of articles but no use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MPPlayableContentManagerContext error in Xcode 6.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166718/mpplayablecontentmanagercontext-error-in-xcode-6-4)

Comment: @carbonr I am not getting any errors while compiling. The moment I load player the application crashing.